# Reducing space between list items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a working `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment`, but for some reason there is a lot of space in between list items, as seen below:

[image]

How can I reduce this space between the list items?

List view item XML:
https://gist.github.com/GauthamRajesh/f46b77eaa04ce26664bfb990d8334437

Fragment java code (where the RecyclerView is used):
https://gist.github.com/GauthamRajesh/7dce43ff4d31572f4603df6ef20be769

Fragment XML:
https://gist.github.com/GauthamRajesh/7eefa04684b00e4b785a3371f4d60389

I have looked at all of the other questions that have similar topics, and I have tried those solutions, but they don't change the spacing.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You have 2 `android:layout_height="match_parent"` that should be `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `match_parent` for your item view *width*, and `wrap_content` for your item view *height*. This will need to be applied to all three container views nested in your item view. So change this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     ...>
>
>     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         ...>
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             ...>
>
>             <TextView .../>
>
>             <TextView .../>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView .../>

            <TextView .../>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
you need to just change in the layout height of the listview that will be android:layout_height="wrap_content "and in Linear layout also as you shown in your code.
```